# How setup primary key for inhered types?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I try create code first by Google.Apis.YouTube.v3.Data.Channel.

My code:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<ChannelBrandingSettings>().Property(x => x.ETag);

modelBuilder.Entity<Google.Apis.YouTube.v3.Data.Channel>().Map(m =>
{
    m.MapInheritedProperties();
    m.ToTable("Youtube_Archieve");
});
```

But when I try Update-Database I get errors:

```
YoutubeAdv.Models.ChannelBrandingSettings: : EntityType 'ChannelBrandingSettings' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.
YoutubeAdv.Models.PropertyValue: : EntityType 'PropertyValue' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.
YoutubeAdv.Models.ImageSettings: : EntityType 'ImageSettings' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.
YoutubeAdv.Models.LocalizedProperty: : EntityType 'LocalizedProperty' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.
YoutubeAdv.Models.LocalizedString: : EntityType 'LocalizedString' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.
```

Comment: Did you define a key?

Comment: The `ETag` should be unique, so use that as primary key in the EF model.

Comment: I haven't ability to add unique key to this classes. So I need make copy of this classes, and use automapper ?